# Valuations and (semi)norms on ring spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, analytic-geometry, ring-spectra

Valuations and seminorms on rings play a big role in number theory and analytic geometry, with seminorms being heavily used in [Berkovich geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkovich_space) and valuations featuring heavily in [adic geometry](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Emurayama/Huber.pdf).

Let's quickly recall their definitions:

> A **valuation on a ring** $A$ is a pair $(\Gamma,\nu)$ consisting of
>
> - *The Value Group.* A totally ordered abelian group $\Gamma$;
> - *The Valuation.* A map of of sets $$\nu\colon A\to\Gamma\mathbin{\textstyle\coprod}\{0\},$$
>   where $\Gamma\mathbin{\textstyle\coprod}\{0\}$ is the totally ordered abelian [group with zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1606639) consisting of the disjoint union of $\Gamma$ with $\{0\}$, with multiplication extending that of $\Gamma$ by declaring $0\cdot0=0$ and $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in\Gamma$, and where we have $0<a$ for all $a\in\Gamma$.
>
> satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. We have $\nu(0)=0$.
> 2. We have $\nu(1)=1$.
> 3. For each $a,b\in A$, we have $\nu(ab)=\nu(a)\nu(b)$.
> 4. For each $a,b\in A$, we have $\nu(a+b)\leq\max(\nu(a),\nu(b))$.

> A **seminorm on a ring $A$** is a map $|-|\colon A\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. We have $|0|=0$.
> 2. We have $|1|=1$.
> 3. For each $a,b\in A$, we have $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$.
> 4. For each $a,b\in A$, we have $|ab|\leq|a||b|$.
>
> Moreover, $|-|$ is a **norm** if $|a|=0$ implies $a=0$.

**Question.** Are there notions of valuations, seminorms, and norms on ring spectra extending the above notions?

Comment: (P.S. By "ring spectra" I mean either commutative algebras in $\mathrm{Sp}$ or $\mathbb{E}_k$-rings for some $1\leq k\leq\infty$, and by "extending" the classical notions I mean that a valuation/seminorm/norm on a ring spectrum $E$ should induce an ordinary valuation/seminorm/norm on $\pi_0(E)$.)

Comment: It does not seem reasonable to consider $E_1$-rings, as this definition does not seem to be reasonable for classical associative rings. On the other hand, it is unclear whether one should only look at connective guys — for example, if one looks at the sphere spectrum, do we need to see the "chromatic information" (for which one should pass to nonconnective guys)?

Comment: In the definition of valuation, the disjoint union is not a group with the structure you give it. In any case, with the correct definitions, if you define valuations and semi norms on a ring spectrum $R$ as those in $\pi_0R$ then this seems to satisfy your conditions.

Comment: @Z.M I hadn't really though of this before, but apparently people do consider valuations on noncommutative rings (e.g. [link](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82749758.pdf)), although I'm not sure how useful they are in that context. Probably we should indeed look at at least $\mathbb{E}_2$-rings. I'm also not sure about connectivity, although I think having such a theory for nonconnective ring spectra as well would certainly be nice

Comment: @FernandoMuro Ah sorry (and thanks)! I've edited the question to correct that. Regarding $\pi_0R$, although that would certainly work I'm not sure if that would be the """right""" definition. E.g. for seminorms I wonder if a better definition would start with finding a homotopy-theoretic version $R$ of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and considering maps of the form $f\colon E\to R$, as then the ordinary seminorm $|-|\colon E\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ would come out by applying $\pi_0$ to $f$.

Comment: Also there might be other conditions one would likely want of those objects, like asking that they also induce graded seminorms/valuations on $\pi_*E$. I'm hoping a theory of seminorms/valuations on ring spectra would be more interesting than just collapsing to the classical theory on $\pi_0$.

Comment: I was not only talking about a "theory for nonconnective rings" — the concept of valuations should be equivalent to the concept of valuation rings, and the question is whether there are nonconnective valuation rings? Let's be a bit simpler — what are fields? For example, would we consider Morava K-theories (not $E_2$, but quasi-commutative) being fields?

Comment: @Z.M Oh I see what you meant now, thanks for clarifying! Hmm... I don't know :/ I think it's also not clear whether the potential generalisations of valuation rings to 'valuation ring spectra' would agree depending on which definition of valuation ring you start with. E.g. I imagine two generalisations starting from the first and fourth definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) might possibly disagree.